# ssh-copy-id not working on Mac

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-keys

I'm following [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id) tutorial and this is what I'm trying

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote_host
```

It says `Permission denied (publickey,password).`

I've also tried `ssh -v remote_host` and verified that

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/praful/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote_host port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/praful/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/praful/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/praful/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/praful/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 55:60:e4:78:c8:98:09:d2:0f:d3:69:73:b9:e0:99:60
debug1: Host is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/praful/.ssh/known_hosts:63
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/praful/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/praful/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@remote_host's password:
```

Comment: *"It says Permission denied (publickey,password)."* - It surely says something more. Show us everything!

Comment: No. It doesnt outputs anything else. How can I see the logs?

Comment: It should at least prompt your for a password, before failing with "Permission denied (password)"

Comment: To see the verbose output, you can use  `-o LogLevel=DEBUG1` (OpenSSH 6.2 or newer only, what you have).

Comment: ssh-copy-id should accept -v I believe, try that. Also what does the server logs show?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the last line is exactly it asking for the password - `root@remote_host's password:`

Comment: @djsmiley2k That's `ssh` output, I was asking about `ssh-copy-id` output + And no, the `ssh-copy-id` does not support `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the private key to `ssh-copy-id` or no key at all as mentioned in the synopsis of the command (from manual page):

```
 ssh-copy-id [...] [-i [identity_file]] [-p port] [-o ssh_option] [user@]hostname
```

or no key at all (it will copy all the keys in standard location in that case). Using the following should do the job:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa remote_host
```

If it will not be helpful, please run

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 remote_host
```

and update the question with the output to investigate more.